# How to handle in Automation script when id is same but class name is different

Tags: selenium

Scenarios is : Click on add button.

Case:
User lands on profile page, then a Loading messsage is displayed , till this message is being displayed the Add button is non-clickable (its id is "add" & class is "btn btnAdd nonclickable") .

When loading message disappears , then Add button is clickable (its ID is "add" & class is "btn btnAdd" ).

I want to automate to click on Add button . But I dont know how much to wait for loading message to complete.

Please help , how can I use class & id locator in this case to automate.

Please reply.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btnAdd']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btnAdd']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.